Check the render method of HomeScreen3
I am getting these errors
 ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `HomeScreen3`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at HomeScreen3.js:19)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at HomeScreen3.js:18)
    in HomeScreen3 (at SceneView.tsx:132)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:218)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at DebugContainer.native.tsx:34)
    in DebugContainer (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:82)
    in MaybeNestedStack (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:325)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:318)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:54)
    in Unknown (at src/index.native.tsx:314)
    in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:27)
    in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:26)
    in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
    in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:313)
    in InnerScreen (at src/index.native.tsx:566)
    in Screen (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:253)
    in SceneView (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:413)
    in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:27)
    in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:26)
    in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
    in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:220)
    in RNSScreenStack (at src/index.native.tsx:227)
    in ScreenStack (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:401)
    in NativeStackViewInner (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:474)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:43)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:473)
    in NativeStackView (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:72)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (at useNavigationBuilder.tsx:718)
    in NavigationContent (at useComponent.tsx:35)
    in Unknown (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:71)
    in NativeStackNavigator (at App.js:29)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:92)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at App.js:28)
    in Provider (at App.js:27)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:433)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.js:26)
    in App (at withDevTools.ios.js:25)
    in withDevTools(App) (at renderApplication.js:57)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:127)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:155)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:67), js engine: hermes

And this is the code please any solution?
import { React } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Image, View } from "react-native";
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";
import { NavOptions } from "./components/NavOptions";
import GoogleplacesAutocomplete from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY } from "@env";
const logoImg = require("./components/LOGO PNG BLACK.png");

const HomeScreen3 = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white h-full`}>
      <View style={tw`p-5`}>
        <Image
          style={{
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            resizeMode: "contain",
          }}
          source={logoImg}
        />

        <GoogleplacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="Where from?"
          styles={{
            container: {
              flex: 0,
            },
            textInput: {
              fontSize: 18,
            },
          }}
          query={{
            key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
            language: "en",
          }}
          nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
          debounce={400}
        />

        <NavOptions />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen3;


first you need to check from which component this error coming so for that you can check by commenting component one by one like:, first comment GoogleplacesAutocomplete and run the app if its working then its the cause and also try same with  
